# [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2]; not working

Tags: iphone, ios7

The code is working fine in ios6 and below but not working in ios7. When views are switched between tab bars the app crashes when same tab is switched second time. In delegateController it is getting crashed at

```
case 1:
    {
        btnMoreSelected=NO;

        //[tabBar setSelectedIndex:0];   (here)

        [imgMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"]];
        [imgMyConnection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect-req.png"]];
        [imgIceBreaker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-ice-brkr.png"]];
        [imgSetting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-nav.png"]];
        [imgSearchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-hover.png"]];
        [imgSearchSeparator setHidden:YES];
        [imgSettingSeprator setHidden:NO];
        [imgIceBreakerSeparator setHidden:NO];
        [imgMyConnectionSeprator setHidden:NO];
    }
        break;
```

The error getting is

```
[_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView frame]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100b1180
```

Please guide for above thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sabareesh That i did yesterday only, actually its the issue related to navigation in ios7.

Comment: OK, if u solved the problem, then please write about how you solved, it may be helpful to someone.